# Downlolad from link pointing to file

Tags: firefox, download, html

When I google for a i.E. a `PDF`, then it frequently happens, that google presents me direct link to a PDF like this example [MIPS Programming](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiNjue7if7vAhVch_0HHYnIBdcQFjAAegQIBhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fdownloads-mips%2Fdocuments%2FMD00086-2B-MIPS32BIS-AFP-6.06.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0nWAc555CdwdRkeMNhheju). Now clicking on the link, the PDF opens in the browser (using Firefox). When I try to download it, then it downloads some `url.html` instread of the PDF.

I usually have to download this `html` file and then look into it for the real path.
So is there some easier way to download this for offline reading, instead of the browser opening it? I have `Download helper` installed, but that doesn't really help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define in Firefox that PDF files are not to be opened in the browser
(which is the default) do this:

- Click the hamburger menu icon
- Select Options
- In the General section, under Applications, set
  "Portable Document Format (PDF)" to "Save File" (instead of the default
  "Open in Firefox):

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was so annoying for a long time now and all the time it was right under my nose.:)